# Как в js заменить значения одного обьекта - свойствами другого обьекта?

Tags: javascript

есть обьект:

```
changed: {
  filter_models: {
    adventure_state: null,
    type_id: null,
    countries: []
  },
  additionally_filter: {
    price_from: null,
    price_to: null,
  },
  region: {
    regions: [],
    cities: [],
    search_neighborns: null
  },

  specifications: {
    fuels: [],
    transmissions: [],
    count_doors: {
      from: null,
      to: null
    },

    colors: {
      items: [],
      metallic: null
    },

    options: []    
  }
}
```

и данные, которые приходят из браузерной строки, нужно перебрать все свойства и заполнить соответствующие им поля в объекте *changed*

Для примера, если пришла строка, я сериализировал ее в объект `params`, и в нем есть `params.filter_models.type_id`, то нужно найти такое же в первом и заменить на значение из второго, и еще один момент, если приходит массив, то все его элементы должны быть переведены в integer и заменены, т.е. `changed.options` должен быть только массивом и все его элементы должны быть интовыми.

Comment: А как данные приходят из браузерной строки? Это как?

Comment: я их сериализирую в такой же обьект, но свойст всех в нем можетм не хватать, или может бить больше, первый обьект идет как еталон. грубо говоря нужно создать третий из свойствами второго, но только такими, которые есть в первом, + есле небудет какого-то свойства во втором, то взять нужно из первого

Comment: Откуда и как вы сериализуете? Приведите пример кода, пожалуйста.

Comment: говорю же, что такой же как и в первый, 1 в 1, только может незватать свойств, например region.regions  может быть а может и небыть во втором

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку встроенного в язык средства сделать то что вы хотите нету, то можете воспользоваться [lodash merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#merge).

```js
// Это объект приходит с браузерной строки(что бы это не значило)
var target = {
  filter_models: {
    adventure_state: "s",
    type_id: 12
  },
  region: {
    regions: ["a", "b"],
    cities: [],
    search_neighborns: null
  },
  specifications: {
    fuels: [],
    transmissions: [],
    count_doors: {
      from: 12,
      to: null
    },
    options: []
  }
};
// Это ваш объект по умолчанию
var source = {
  filter_models: {
    adventure_state: null,
    type_id: null,
    countries: []
  },
  additionally_filter: {
    price_from: null,
    price_to: null,
  },
  region: {
    regions: [],
    cities: [],
    search_neighborns: null
  },
  specifications: {
    fuels: [],
    transmissions: [],
    count_doors: {
      from: null,
      to: null
    },
    colors: {
      items: [],
      metallic: null
    },
    options: []
  }
};
// Результат
var result = _.merge({}, source, target);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю пример реализации метода, который присваивает полям объекта значения из соответствующих полей другого объекта.
Если в целевом объекте поле отсутствует, то оно не создается. Методы не копируются. Из вложенных массивов копируются только элементы простых (не объектных) типов.

```js
Object.prototype.assignValuesFrom = function(sourceObj) {
  assign(this, sourceObj); 

  function assign(dst, src) {
    for (let key in src) {
      if (!dst.hasOwnProperty(key) || (typeof src[key] === 'function'))
        continue; 
      if (src[key] instanceof Array) {
        for (let i = 0; i < src[key].length; i++) {
          if (!(src[key][i] instanceof Object))
            dst[key][i] = src[key][i]; 
        }
        continue; 
      }
      if (src[key] instanceof Object) {
        assign(dst[key], src[key]);
        continue; 
      }
      dst[key] = src[key]; 
    }
  }
}


  // исходный объект
let changed = {
  filter_models: {
    adventure_state: null,
    type_id: null,
    countries: []
  },
  additionally_filter: {
    price_from: null,
    price_to: null,
  },
  region: {
    regions: [],
    cities: [],
    search_neighborns: null
  },
  specifications: {
    fuels: [],
    transmissions: [],
    count_doors: {
      from: null,
      to: null
    },
    colors: {
      items: [],
      metallic: null
    },
    options: []    
  }
}; 

  // объект, полученный "из браузерной строки"
let params = {
  filter_models: {
    adventure_state: 1,
    type_id: 'someId',
    countries: ['RF', 'UK']
  },
  specifications: {
    options: [0, 42]
  }
}

  // копируем исходный объект changed
let copy = Object.assign({}, changed);
  // копируем из объекта params значения тех полей, которые присутствуют в копии changed
copy.assignValuesFrom(params); 
  // копируем значение из еще одного объекта, в литеральной записи
copy.assignValuesFrom({
  region: {
    search_neighborns: true
  }
}); 

  // вывод результата
document.body.innerHTML = `
<pre style="font: 14px monospace;">
  ${JSON.stringify(copy, null, 2)}
</pre>`;
```

---

Почему не ограничиться стандартным `Object.assign()` - потому что при копировании вложенных объектов, он выполняет именно копирование, а не слияние. То есть, в данном случае, после `copy = Object.assign(changed, params);` вложенный объект `copy.specifications` содержал бы только массив `options`, "потеряв" остальные поля - а это не то, что требуется по задаче.

---

p.s.: Копию объекта создавать не обязательно, конечно же - можно использовать тот же самый, `changed.assignValuesFrom(...);`. В примере создается отдельный объект, так как это упоминалось в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805924/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-js-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0#comment1275239_805924)

> ...грубо говоря нужно создать третий из свойствами второго, но только такими, которые есть в первом...